# Json для android

Tags: android, json

У меня есть Json, я хочу сделать так, что бы по ID создавалась кнопка, а при нажатие по нему, открывался браузер и  переходила на ссылку которая указана в json, я просто новичок, весь гугл облазил,и ничего не понятно. Делаю для android в Android studio.
Вот пример JSON:

```
{"id":1,"link":"http:vk.com","name":"VK"}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете ввиду под "что бы по ID создавалась кнопка", то есть сколько id столько кнопок? или Что?

Comment: Да, то есть там к каждому id, своя кнопка

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перед вами обычный `Json` объект. Берете и парсите его.

```
String json = "{\"id\":1,\"link\":\"http://www.vk.com\",\"name\":\"VK\"}";

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
String url = obj.getString("link");
String name = obj.getString("name");
```

Теперь у вас есть ссылка и текст для кнопки. Находим кнопку. Ставим ей программно текст и пишем слушатель.

```
Button go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
go.setText(name);
go.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
}
});
```

Почитайте [эту](http://java-help.ru/android-json/) статью. Там все про `JSON` расписано.

**UPD**

Насчёт списка - все просто. Итак, поехали. Для начала распарсим `JSON` массив.

```
String json = "[{\"id\":1,\"link\":\"http://www.vk.com\",\"name\":\"VK\"}, {\"id\":1,\"link\":\"http://www.google.com\",\"name\":\"Google\"},{\"id\":1,\"link\":\"http://www.yandex.ru\",\"name\":\"Yandex\"}";
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
int size = array.length();
String[] links = new String[size];
String[] names = new String[size];
for(int n = 0; n < size; n++) {
JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(n);
links[n] = obj.getString("link");
names[n] = obj.getString("name");
}
```

Все, у нас есть массивы со ссылками и названиями сайтов. Далее мы должны создать `ListView` в разметке.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Теперь создаём адаптер и забьем список данными.

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

И слушатель для списка.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
      int position, long id) {
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(links[position-1]));
startActivity(i);
  }
});
```

Позицию нажатого айтема (элемента списка) мы используем как индекс для массива ссылок.

**FULL CODE**

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import org.json.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.AdapterView.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.net.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.util.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
String[] links, names;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    String json = "[{\"id\":1,\"link\":\"http://www.vk.com\",\"name\":\"VK\"}, {\"id\":1,\"link\":\"http://www.google.com\",\"name\":\"Google\"},{\"id\":1,\"link\":\"http://www.yandex.ru\",\"name\":\"Yandex\"}]";
    try{
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
    int size = array.length();
    links = new String[size];
    names = new String[size];
    for(int n = 0; n < size; n++) {
        JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(n);
        links[n] = obj.getString("link");
        names[n] = obj.getString("name");
}
} catch (JSONException e){
    Log.d("$", e.toString());
}
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(links[position]));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
}
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="top">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Как я понял, вы не знаете элементарных вещей в разработке, так что приведу хорошие сайты для обучения

[StartAndroid](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom.html)

[Сайт Александра Климова](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/)

Чтобы научиться, нужно только читать блоги и много практиковаться. **Гуглите**. Это самое главное. Все, что нужно уже есть. Нам остаётся только разбираться во всем этом.

Ах, да, скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Счастливого кодинга!

Comment: Получаю с сервера, так тоесть много id и т.д

Comment: Тогда вам нужно создать `ListView` и выводить в него список. Вам именно кнопки нужны? Со списком это будет выглядеть каряво, советую без них. Дополнить ответ?

Comment: Надо именно с кнопками, просто мне потом это  c теликом связать, то есть, что бы в ручную не водит на пульте ссылку, а просто на кнопку нажал и открылась ссылка, но это потом, мне надо, что бы хотя бы на телефоне открывалось, а за ссылку спасибо. почитаю

Comment: Могу дополнить ответ. Нужно?

Comment: Я думаю, что нужно.

Comment: Ругается android studio, типо "class" or "interface" or enum expected

Comment: Весь код в ответе написан от руки без студий с телефона. Ясно дело где-то ошибки. Что не так? Что именно подчёркивает красным? Прикрепите скриншот к вопросу

Comment: Вы где-то что-то неправильно вставили, покажите код целиком.

Comment: 2 ошибки выдало

Comment: Что сейчас? Какие ошибки? Возможно, у вас над секцией импортов отсутствует строка `package ...`, нет?

Comment: Все, разобрался, большое спасибо вам, и за сайты тоже)

Comment: Получилось? Работает?)

Comment: Ща, попробую запустить на телефоне и отпишусь

Comment: Вот такую ошибку выдает "diamond operator is not suppoted in -source 1.6( use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)"

Comment: Все исправил, и все работает

Answer (score 2):

```
String json = "{\"id\":1,\"link\":\"http:vk.com\",\"name\":\"VK\"}";

LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout); //layout в который поместить кнопку
try {
    JSONObject rootJSON = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(json));
    String name = rootJSON.getString("name");
    String link = rootJSON.getString("link");

    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText(name);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(link)));
        }
    });

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    layout.addView(button, params);

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: А в папке layout, в XML файле, что надо прописать? А  если у меня Json на сервере, то как?

Comment: И еще, допустим у меня несколько id,link,name, то как мне тут поступить?

Comment: В этом ответе кнопка создаётся программно и рассчитана на один id. Для множества кнопок неизвестного количество есть списки.

Comment: @Shufler3 "в папке layout, в XML файле" нужно написать LinearLayout; "допустим у меня несколько id,link,name" этот код можно вынести в метод и давать на вход name и link, все конечно зависит от ваших требований.

Comment: @katso Как мне это сделать?